# What are the memory implications of the sharedInstance pattern under ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using the common singleton pattern as follows:

```
+ (SomeClass *)sharedInstance {
    static SomeClass *__sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        __sharedInstance = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    });

    return __sharedInstance;
}
```

I understand that the SomeClass object gets instantiated the first time I call [SomeClass sharedInstance], however, **when does SomeClass get dealloc'd?**

This is under ARC so when does the compiler release the SomeClass static object? Is it guaranteed to be around for the rest of the life of my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the declaration of `__sharedInstance` is inside `sharedInstance`'s scope, it cannot be accessed directly by any other methods. This means that no one else can set it to `nil`, and therefore it will be kept until your app will be terminated.

It's also worth mentioning that you cannot be certain that the `dealloc` method of your singleton will be called when the system frees your memory on termination, mainly because:

1. The OS itself may handle the termination of the process, without the Objective-C runtime calling your `dealloc` method before that happens.
2. Say that you do get a `dealloc` method, then you cannot predict the order of object destruction while terminating (such as frameworks that you use), making your code unreliable.

Comment: +1 You forgot one detail;  *This is a feature of shared instances; by definition, they should not be deallocated ever during the running session of your application.  If your application is terminated, the system will automatically reclaim any resources.*

Comment: Since static variables are `strong` by default, the object will be retained by ARC. This is what keeps the object alive for the duration.

Comment: More strongly and as @maddy implies;  it is guaranteed that your `dealloc` method *will not be called* given the code as written unless your program violates memory management patterns.